# How do I render a 2D Sprite using WebGL?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, html5-canvas, dart, webgl

I'm struggling to render a 2D Sprite to a Canvas using Dart and WebGL. I can find very few examples of this online; most are either 3D, or contain tons of spaghetti code with no real explanation of what they're doing. I'm trying to do the simplest thing that renders a sprite.

So far, I've managed to render a green square (two triangles) on a canvas. The bit I'm struggling with, is how to change this from a green square to using my texture (the texture is loaded and bound correctly, I believe). I think this will need changes to the shaders (to take texture co-ords, instead of colour) and something to pass texture coords relating to the vertices in the buffer.

This code [also exists in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/DanTup/97670def346fe4bd053a).

Note: This is just a throwaway sample; most of the code lives in the constructor; I'm not too interested in how tidy the code is for now; I can tidy up when I can see a sprite on the screen!

Note: I'm not interested in using a third-party library; I'm doing this to learn WebGL!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MySecondGame</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="1024" height="768"></canvas>

    <div style="display: none;">
      <img id="img-player" src="assets/player.png" />
    </div>

    <script id="vertex" type="x-shader">
      attribute vec2 aVertexPosition;

      void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
      }
    </script>
    <script id="fragment" type="x-shader">
      #ifdef GL_ES
      precision highp float;
      #endif

      uniform vec4 uColor;

      void main() {
        gl_FragColor = uColor;
      }
    </script>

    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'dart:async';
      import 'dart:html';
      import 'dart:math';
      import 'dart:typed_data';
      import 'dart:web_gl';

      Game game;

      main() {
        game = new Game(document.querySelector('canvas'));
      }

      class Game {
        RenderingContext _gl;
        Buffer vbuffer;
        int numItems;
        Texture playerTexture;
        double elapsedTime;
        double fadeAmount;

        Game(CanvasElement canvas) {
          _gl = canvas.getContext3d();
          playerTexture = _gl.createTexture();
          _gl.bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, playerTexture);
          _gl.texImage2DUntyped(TEXTURE_2D, 0, RGBA, RGBA, UNSIGNED_BYTE, document.querySelector('#img-player'));
          _gl.texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, NEAREST);
          _gl.texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
          _gl.generateMipmap(TEXTURE_2D);
          _gl.bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, null);

          var vsScript = document.querySelector('#vertex');
          var vs = _gl.createShader(VERTEX_SHADER);
          _gl.shaderSource(vs, vsScript.text);
          _gl.compileShader(vs);

          var fsScript = document.querySelector('#fragment');
          var fs = _gl.createShader(FRAGMENT_SHADER);
          _gl.shaderSource(fs, fsScript.text);
          _gl.compileShader(fs);

          var program = _gl.createProgram();
          _gl.attachShader(program, vs);
          _gl.attachShader(program, fs);
          _gl.linkProgram(program);

          if (!_gl.getShaderParameter(vs, COMPILE_STATUS))
            print(_gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs));

          if (!_gl.getShaderParameter(fs, COMPILE_STATUS))
            print(_gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs));

          if (!_gl.getProgramParameter(program, LINK_STATUS))
            print(_gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));

          var aspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;
          var vertices = new Float32List.fromList([
            -0.5, 0.5 * aspect, 0.5, 0.5 * aspect,  0.5, -0.5 * aspect,  // Triangle 1
            -0.5, 0.5 * aspect, 0.5,-0.5 * aspect, -0.5, -0.5 * aspect   // Triangle 2
          ]);

          vbuffer = _gl.createBuffer();
          _gl.bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);                                       
          _gl.bufferData(ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, STATIC_DRAW);
          numItems = vertices.length ~/ 2;

          _gl.useProgram(program);

          var uColor = _gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uColor");
          _gl.uniform4fv(uColor, new Float32List.fromList([0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 1.0]));

          var aVertexPosition = _gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexPosition");
          _gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aVertexPosition);
          _gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPosition, 2, FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

          window.animationFrame.then(_gameLoop);
        }

        _gameLoop(num time) {
          elapsedTime = time;
          _update();
          _render();
          window.animationFrame.then(_gameLoop);
        }

        _update() {
          // Use sine curve for fading. Sine is -1-1, so tweak to be 0 - 1.
          fadeAmount = (sin(elapsedTime/1000) / 2) + 0.5;
        }

        _render() {
          // Set colour for clearing to.
          _gl.clearColor(fadeAmount, 1 - fadeAmount, 0.0, 1.0);
          // Clear.
          _gl.clear(RenderingContext.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

          _gl.bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, playerTexture);
          _gl.drawArrays(TRIANGLES, 0, numItems);
          _gl.bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, null);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Tagging this with `opengl` too because I believe the solution is likely the same for WebGL/OpenGL).

Comment: [try these tutorials](http://webglfundamentals.org)?

Comment: @gman Thanks; hasn't seen this ones, will have a look through!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, managed to make this work. You can [see the full diff in a gist here](https://gist.github.com/DanTup/97670def346fe4bd053a/revisions).

I might be wrong; but it seems that I was expecting to set the data in the buffers while I was setting them up; but I couldn't find any way to say which data was for which buffer. I split the code into some setup code:

```
vbuffer = _gl.createBuffer();
_gl.bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
_gl.bufferData(ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, STATIC_DRAW);
numItems = vertices.length ~/ 2;

tbuffer = _gl.createBuffer();
_gl.bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, tbuffer);                                       
_gl.bufferData(ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoords, STATIC_DRAW);

aVertexPosition = _gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexPosition");
_gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aVertexPosition);

aTextureCoord = _gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aTextureCoord");
_gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aTextureCoord);

uSampler = _gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uSampler");
```

and some rendering code:

```
_gl.bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
_gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPosition, 2, FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

_gl.bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, tbuffer);
_gl.vertexAttribPointer(aTextureCoord, 2, FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

_gl.bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, playerTexture);
_gl.uniform1i(uSampler, 0);

_gl.drawArrays(TRIANGLES, 0, numItems);
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct (it feels like I'm sending the same vertex and textureCoord every frame), but it's working.

[image: I MADE A GAME!!!!111]

Comment: You're not sending any data every frame. You telling WebGL which data to use that you already sent.

Comment: @gman Oh, yes! I knew that was the case with the texture, but somehow confused my vertex buffer with the actual array. It's been a long afternoon! :)

Comment: @gman Does this otherwise seem same; have I got the right code in setup vs in the loop?

Comment: Yes, it seems sane. Most people would probably add a matrix multiply here `gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);` as in `gl_Position = uMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);` this would let them transform, rotate, and scale the sprite. Also, FYI, you can change `aVertexPosition` to `vec4` and then it's just `gl_Position = uMatrix * aVertexPosition;` because if you only supply 2 values for an attribute with `gl.vertexBufferPointer` but use `vec4` in the shader `z = 0` and `w = 1` by default for attributes.